# Getting error when adding element to value array of hashmap

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

I have a text file that I'm reading from. My goal is to create a hashmap of every word in the text file with the index where it appears.  An index is defined as a section of the text.  In this case every 100 characters is considered an index.  For some reason I'm getting an error when I try to add indices to the array.  The error says "cannot find symbol."  I'm very new to java as in I just started coding in it yesterday so any help would be very appreciated.  My code is below:

```
import java.io.*;  //needed for File class below
import java.util.*;  //needed for Scanner class below

public class readIn {

    public static void readInWords(String fileName) {
        try {
            //open up the file
            Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
            HashMap hm = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>(); // Tells Java What datatypes are in the hashmap hm
            //Map<String, ArrayList<String>> myMap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
            int length = 0;
            int total = 0;
            int page = 0;
            while (input.hasNext()) {
                //read in 1 word at a time and increment our count
                String x = input.next();
                if (total < 100) {
                    length = x.length();
                    total = total += length;
                } else {
                    total = 0;
                    page++;
                }
                if (hm.get(x) == null) {
                    hm.put(x, new ArrayList<Integer>(page));
                } else {
                    hm.get(x).add(page);
                }

            }
            System.out.println(length);
            System.out.println(hm);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Something went really wrong...");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int x = 10;  //can read in from user or simply set here

        String fileName = "test.txt";
        readInWords(fileName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you specify on which line the error occurs?

Comment: Sure, it's on line 28.  The "hm.get(x).add(page)"

Comment: There is so many problems with your code but your specific compiler error can be solve by changing `HashMap hm = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();` to `HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> hm = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>();`

Comment: print the stacktrace error in the catch block.

Comment: Thanks Amin.  What are other issues with the code that you can see.  As I said before I literally began learning Java yesterday and would love to get additional tips.

Comment: `hm` is defined as a *raw* `HashMap`. Do not use *raw* generics. Specify the generic type arguments, and you won't have to cast values.

Comment: So define what's going to be in the hashmap when I declare it right?

Answer (score 0):

// you need to type cast hm.get(x) into an ArrayList like

((ArrayList)hm.get(x)).add(page);

Answer (score 0):

You need to change :

```
 HashMap hm = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
```

to

```
   Map<String,ArrayList<Integer>> hm =  new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

If you don't define the map type, [get()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get(java.lang.Object)) return an `Object`. By defining `Map<String,ArrayList<Integer>>` get will return an `ArrayList<Integer>>`.

Use `ArrayList<Integer>` rather then  `ArrayList<String>` because you store integers in the arraylist, and not strings.

Comment: Feedback would be appreciated.